# Extjs TypeError: Ext.grid.header is undefined

Tags: extjs

i have always this Error: **TypeError: Ext.grid.header is undefined**

first i create my store, load it with my datas and than when i will create the grid Panel this error occurs.
The data from my database to get right and the 'Store' is loaded correctly.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  xtype: 'grid',
  selType: 'rowmodel',
  store:  Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('store'),
  columns: [ ... ]
});
```

Comment: Are you calling Ext.grid.Header anywhere in the code? Did you include the plugins `plugins : [         Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',{
clicksToEdit:2
})]`

Comment: No i´m not calling Ext.grid.Header anywhere, should i do that?

And i don´t include the plugins, when i include it in my grid than occurs this Error: TypeError: Ext.grid.ColumnManager is not a constructor

Comment: Oh sry, it´s my fault. I forgot to add the Ext.grid.ColumnManager by the requires. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Just to add, there is no need to inform xtype if you are specifying 'Ext.grid.Panel' already